# How to stop accessing shared preferences from another application in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an application where I want to save username and password on Remember checkbox is checked.

I done the above requirement using Shared Preferences. But i created another application and tried to read the username and password and got the values successfully.

My Client needs the security so how can i stop other apps to read my shared preferences.

```
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences()
{
   return this.mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
public void saveLong(String paramString, long paramLong)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = getSharedPreferences().edit();
    localEditor.putLong(paramString, paramLong);
    localEditor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `MODE_PRIVATE` is not enough, you can encrypt the data, turn it into `base64`, and save it as a string in the `Preferences` object. Reverse the process on the way back. Your data will be accessible, but illegible.